# how to get address from gms marker from google map?

Tags: ios, google-maps, gmsmapview

How to get latitude longitude on this method?

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView )mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker )marker;
```

i want to get address when didEndDraggingMarker is called..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `latitude` and `longitude` from the `marker.position`. use the reverse geocoding to get the address of the location

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    NSLog(@"You tapped at %f,%f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
}
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
    NSLog(@"tapped");
}

- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didBeginDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{
     isDragging = YES;
    NSLog(@"didBeginDraggingMarker:");
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{
    isDragging = NO;
    NSLog(@"marker dragged to location: %f,%f", marker.position.latitude, marker.position.longitude);

    NSLog(@"didEndDraggingMarker");

}
```